# Simulate from a Latent Class Model specifying the dependency structure of the variables

Tags: r, dependencies, classification, simulation

I am trying to simulate some categorical variables from a latent class model in R. I know that there exist the poLCA function poLCA.simdata, but I need to be able to specify the dependency structure among the variables. Is there an option that allows me to do it? Or another function that can be used?

In particular I need to simulate n observations and K variables each of which belong to 2/3 latent classes. I need to be able to specify that the K variables are highly dependent (high chi-square), or independent, or some variables are conditionally independent from others.

Thanks to anyone who will help.